# Vue-Bootstrap Add special row in table

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

Is it possible to add a spcial row, like a horizontal split, in a b-table component?

Can the position of the special row be based on the line number? Like always between row 2 and 3.

Example:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|              |                |                   |                  |
|              |                |                   |                  |
|              |                |                   |                  |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|              |                |                   |                  |
|              |                |                   |                  |
|              |                |                   |                  |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                     Some special text here                           |
|                   Split the table into two parts                     |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|              |                |                   |                  |
|              |                |                   |                  |
|              |                |                   |                  |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|              |                |                   |                  |
|              |                |                   |                  |
|              |                |                   |                  |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|              |                |                   |                  |
|              |                |                   |                  |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the colspan attribute

Add an identifier to your data:

```
rows: [
      { id: 1, name: 'Bill', handle: 'bill' },
      { id: 2, name: 'Bob', handle: 'bob', special: 2 },
    ]
```

Then add a v-if on the `<tr>` elements in your template:

```
<template v-for="row in rows">
      <tr v-if="!row.special">
        <td>{{ row.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.handle }}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr v-else>
        <td :colspan="row.special">
            {{ row.name}}
        </td>
      </tr>
</template>
```

example: https://codepen.io/ellisdod/pen/jObVJxN